# advantages of randomly chose pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In quick sort we can choose a pivot value in different ways. Randomly choose a pivot value is one of that. It says that when we choose the pivot value randomly , it minimize tha chance of having O(n^2). Can anyone explain how does it happen? Are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both random and non-random pick produce an algorithm whose expected run time is Theta(n*log(n)), if the expected value is averaged over all possible inputs (permutations).

In practice not all input permutations are equally probable. In particular you often get sorted or nearly sorted arrays when pick-first gives Theta(n^2) complexity. On top of that if your picking algorithm is deterministic, an attacker can craft a nasty permutation to make your algorithm quadratic, thus achieving denial of service.

Picking random element as the pivot guards against these non-random cases.

Comment: This answer is overloading the term expected run time. One case is really about average case complexity (i.e. assuming inputs are random and equally probably) and not really relevant to the question, and the other is more appropriate usage of the term: irrespective of input, only the algorithm's random choices effect the runtime (as in Nemo's answer).

Comment: @Confusius Indeed. Little inaccuracy saves a ton of explanation (but you can overdo it.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a mathematical proof that the expected runtime with a random pivot is Theta(n logn).

The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) has a section on that.